# Query for a field value that is a sub string of the search value

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

If I have the following documents,

```
`
db.articles.insert(
   [
     { _id: 1, subject: "coffee", author: "xyz", views: 50 },
     { _id: 2, subject: "Coffee Shopping", author: "efg", views: 5 },
     { _id: 3, subject: "Baking a cake", author: "abc", views: 90  },
     { _id: 4, subject: "baking", author: "xyz", views: 100 },
     { _id: 5, subject: "Café Con Leche", author: "abc", views: 200 },
     { _id: 6, subject: "Сырники", author: "jkl", views: 80 },
     { _id: 7, subject: "coffee and cream", author: "efg", views: 10 },
     { _id: 8, subject: "Cafe con Leche", author: "xyz", views: 10 }
   ]
)
`
```

How does one display the following result

```
`
{ _id: 3, subject: "Baking a cake", author: "abc", views: 90  }
`
```

someone searches for the term `cakemaster` ?

I have tried the following,

```
`
const regex = new RegExp(escapeRegex(req.query.search), 'gi');
db.articles.createIndex( { subject: "text" } )
db.articles.find({$text:{$search: "cakes"}})
`
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Have you created "text" index on `subject` field?

Comment: Will edit the post, but yes I have

Comment: For me the above code is working fine

Comment: sorry, I had the term wrong, instead of 'cakes' I wanted 'cakemaster'. Edited the post as well

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53652282/how-does-mongodb-text-search-works/53659872#53659872

Comment: Thanks, but my question is not about how $text search works, but how do I get the specified result? Is it possible to look for fields that match the root of the searched value

Comment: `cake` and `cakemaster` both are totally different words. You cannot get the desired result with that different keywords. The commented link supposed to explain how `text` index works and that's what you must read.

Comment: So just to confirm, there is no way of getting results that contain the 'cake' string even though the query 'cakemaster' contains 'cake' inside?